# How do I convert specific chars with my function without parsing errors?

Tags: haskell

I want to convert Chars to Strings with a certain function, but it keeps outputting errors

This is my code:

```
convert1 :: Char -> String
convert1 x = 
if [x] == "+"
    then x
    else if [x] == "*"
        then x
        else if [x] == "^"
            then x
            else menge ((read [x]) :: Int)
```

menge is a function that takes Integers and outputs Strings - I know this isn't that nice, but the chars this will get will always be the three characters above or a number.
I'm getting the result

```
operations.hs:12:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
12 | if [x] == "+"
   | ^
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `if` needs to be indented further to the right. But after that you're going to have other problems, because you've specified return type as `String`, but trying to return `x`, which is a `Char`

Comment: Haskell has `Char` literals: `if x == '+'`, e.g.

Comment: This is also simpler to define piecewise: `convert1 '+' = "+"`, `convert '*' = "*"`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a heavily nested `if` expression, just define the function piecewise. (This saves you from having to worry about indentation, although the whole body has to be indented at least one more space for it to be considered a continuation of the definition started by `convert1 x =`.)

```
convert1 :: Char -> String
convert1 '+' = "+"
convert1 '*' = "*"
convert1 '^' = "^"
convert1 x = menge (read [x])
```

If `menge` has the type `Int -> String`, you 
don't need to provide the type for `read` explicitly; the compiler can infer it from the fact that `menge` expects an `Int`.